# django how can i return name of a month in a template from a dropdown list

Tags: python, django, date

In my web app,i have a search functionality which in fact searching data, based on selected month and year.I am using a simple date and year selection drop down menu.but can't render the **name of the selected month**  in my search result template.That is, if i select January month,then its in fact **returning the value 1,instead of returning the name of the month**.Now This my drop down menu for selecting month and year to search item.

```
<form role="form" method='post' action='{% url 'user_commission_results'%}'>
             <tr>
              {% csrf_token %}

                 <td><select name="month" value="">

                    <option value="1">January</option>
                    <option value="2">February</option>
                    <option value="3">March</option>
                    <option value="4">April</option>
                    <option value="5">May</option>
                    <option value="6">June</option>
                    <option value="7">July</option>
                    <option value="8">August</option>
                    <option value="9">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
                     </select></td>
                  <td><select name="year">
                    <option value="2010">2010</option>
                    <option value="2011">2011</option>
                    <option value="2012">2012</option>
                    <option value="2013">2013</option>
                    <option value="2014">2014</option>
                    <option value="2015">2015</option>
                    <option value="2016">2016</option>
                    <option value="2017">2017</option>
                    <option value="2018">2018</option>
                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                    <option value="2020">2020</option>
                    <option value="2021">2021</option>
                 </select></td>
            <td>
            <input type='submit' value='search' />
            </td>
            </tr>
            </form>
```

and this is the **views.py** where i have stored the selected(request.POST) month and year in a variable namely **month** and **year** and returning as a context, to show in the resulting template.here it is,

```
def user_commission_results(request):
    month = request.POST.get('month')
    year = request.POST.get('year')

    context = RequestContext(request)
    commission_results = UserCommission.objects.filter(created_time__year=year,created_time__month=month,user=request.user).order_by('-download')

    return render_to_response('photo/user_commission_results.html',{'commission_results':commission_results,'month':month,'year':year},context)
```

here you can see that i have stored the selected month and year in variables and passed as a context.

Now in my resulting template ,if i use `{{month}}` to show the selected month, its in fact showing the **value of the month** not the **name of the month**.

As example ,if i select March as a month,then it returning the value 3 instead of the name of the month.I can understand ,it's in fact returning the value,cause in my drop down menu,i have set value 3 for the month of March.Now my question is, how can i show the name of the month instead of the value of the month?cause i can't set value something like that

```
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
................................
................................
```

because,i have set a search query in my views.py where the query is looking for the value of the month to search item,so i have to set value 1,2 or 3 ....  for the month Jan,Feb and March .......

**Update**:

According to Blackeagle52's answer,i have rewrite my views.py.

**views.py**

```
def user_commission_results(request):
    month = request.POST.get('month')
    year = request.POST.get('year')
    dt = datetime.datetime(year,month,1)
    verbose_month = dt.strftime('%B')

    context = RequestContext(request)
    commission_results = UserCommission.objects.filter(created_time__year=year,created_time__month=month,user=request.user).order_by('-download')
    total_commission = sum([i.commission for i in commission_results])
    return render_to_response('photo/user_commission_results.html',{'commission_results':commission_results,'total_commission':total_commission,'month':verbose_month,'year':year},context)
```

but now i am facing the error,

```
TypeError at /showphoto/user_commission_results/
an integer is required
```

at line

```
dt = datetime.datetime(year,month,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new datetime object, and get its name by `strftime`.

`import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), 1) \
    if year and month else datetime.datetime.now()
verbose_month = dt.strftime('%B')`

**Edit:** POST variables are strings, so we need to cast them to an int. But be careful, there could be cases where year and/or month stay empty. So catched with an inline if statement

Comment: thanks for your answer,i have set my views.py code according to your answer,but now i am facting the error namely "An integer is required" in the line  dt=datetime.datetime(year,month,1) @Blackeagle52

Comment: Ahh, damn it, I forget you get a string from your POST. So you still have to cast it it an int. I will edit my answer.

Comment: yeah,my guess was right,in fact the month and year passing as string.

Comment: Also did an extra edit, because on initial load, before posting the range, month and year will be `None`, don't know what you want to do in that case, but I picked `now()` as a default.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Calendar API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name).

You can't get the string value if you set the numeric value in the option's value field.

So you should get it inside your view using for example the Calendar API, that is :

```
calendar.month_name[1] 
'January'
```

Answer (score 2):

Such display things should be controlled at the template level, and you should also use a form to generate your ... form, which will make life easier for you when validating and displaying errors as well.

If you combine all that together, along with having the database doing the sums for you, you could end up with something like this:

```
import calendar, datetime

from django.db.models import Sum
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms

MONTHS = tuple(zip(range(1,13), (calendar.month_name[i] for i in range(1,13))))
YEARS = tuple(zip(range(2010,2022), range(2010,2022)))

class CalendarPickerForm(forms.Form):
     month = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MONTHS)
     year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YEARS)


def user_commission_results(request):
    form = CalendarPickerForm(request.GET or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        year = form.cleaned_data['year']
        month = form.cleaned_data['month']
        date_obj = datetime.datetime.date(int(year), int(month), 1)
        objs = UserCommission.objects.filter(created_time__year=year,
                                             created_time__month=month,
                                             user=request.user).order_by('-download')
        total_commission = objs.aggregate(total_comm=Sum('commission'))['total_comm']

        return render(request,
                      'photo/user_commission_results.html',
                      {'commission_results': objs,
                       'total_commission': total_commission,
                       'date_obj': date_obj})
     return render(request, 'search_form.html', {'form': form})
```

In your template, you can render the month name with the [date filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

```
{{ date_obj|date:"F" }} # December
{{ date_obj|date:"Y" }} # 2014
```

Comment: i am facing error `tuple() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)` in the line `YEARS = tuple(range(2010,2022), range(2010,2022))`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like making a switch statement where you resolve the number to a month name again. imho that's more like a quick and dirty fix than a real solution but it will do the trick.